# display sql table in umbraco page

Tags: sql, umbraco

I get some some code from net to display table in Umbra co page. but it doesn't wont work. Here is my code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@using System.Xml.Linq
@using System.Text
@using System.Data
@using System.Data.SqlClient
@using MVCUmbraco.Models
@using System.Web.Configuration

<h2>dowload list</h2>
    <div>
@{
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["employeeDBContext"].ToString());
    da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from files", con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    List<upload> product = new List<upload>();
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        product.Add(new upload() { id = int.Parse(dr[0].ToString()), name = dr[1].ToString(), filetype = dr[2].ToString(), filepath = dr[3].ToString() });
    }

} 
</div>
    <div>
<ul>
@foreach (var row in product)
{
 <li>
 @row.id
 </li>

        <li>
     @row.name
     </li><li>
     @row.filetype
     </li><li>
     @row.filepath
     </li>
    }
    </UL> 
        </div>
```

I need to display the data of table files to my view.
I have code to insert into SQL table but I don't know how to display records from SQL table.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you get an error? If so, it would be useful to include the error message that you're getting.